# How to alert Delete Sucessfully after Destroy of Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid to display data. Now I know how to ask confirmation of Deletion though kendo grid. Now I want to display alert like Delete Successfully after sucessfull deletion of the record. How can I do it? Here is my kendo grid code.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<RxConnectEntities.DeleteFileDTO>().Name("deleteList")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.DeleteFaxID).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FaxName).Width(100).Title("File Name");
        columns.Bound(p => p.PerformedDateTime).Width(75).Title("Archive Date").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text("Move"); }).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FilePath).Hidden(true);
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Are you sure want to Move this Finance File?"))
    .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(true))
        .Scrollable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
        .Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
        .Groupable()
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(false).Operators(operators => operators.ForString(str => str.Clear().StartsWith("Starts with").Contains("contains").IsEqualTo("Is equal to"))))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:738px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax().ServerOperation(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.DeleteFileID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetFileList", "Fax"))
    .Destroy(update => update.Action("MoveFileFromArchiveToQueue", "Operation"))
        ))
```

Comment: How do you intend to "delete" the object? If you do it per AJAX, you can just send back a confirmation message and display that.

Comment: @AndreiV I am using kendo grid's destroy event for deletion.

Comment: The command name is `destroy`, the event is actually called [`remove`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-remove) (a technicality). I need a bit more information here. How do you bind your data? You could register your "delete function" on the `remove` event and send an AJAX request to the server, with the ID of the record you are deleting. Get back a message (JsonResult) with the confirmation of your database action (some will argue that you must use a `POST` since you're modifying the database...). Anyway, it really depends on how your data in bound to the grid.

Comment: @AndreiV here is my code

Comment: Hmm... you're deleting using the helper. I don't really know what the `MoveFileFromArchiveToQueue` does, specifically what it returns. You could try to play around with the [`remove` event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridEventBuilder#methods-Remove(System-String)). Add a JavaScript function and see if you can get a confirmation from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this:

```
.Events(events => events.Change("onChange").Remove("YourFunctionForAfterDelete")
```

Then confirm from that...

The alternative being to create a custom command to delete, use ajax and return success/error messages into a dialog or something similar, which is better but take a little more code and reading.

```
columns.Command(commands =>
                      {
                          commands.Edit() data items
                          commands.Custom("Delete").Click("DeleteByAJAX"); // The "destroy" command removes data items
                      }).Width(95);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above method and could not get it to work as needed. I instead subscribed to the onRequestEnd method. I had several alert messages I needed to throw. 1 for successfully adding a record, 1 for successfully deleting a record, and 1 for successfully updating a record.

I populated a ViewBag in the controller based upon the CRUD operation that was occurring.

I then checked for the Viewbag's value in the View and tossed the correct bootstrap alert upon the page reloading...

```
@if (ViewBag.Alert == "Success")
{
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Record has been successfully added.</strong>
</div>
}

@if (ViewBag.Alert == "Deleted")
{
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Record has been successfully deleted.</strong>
</div>
}

@if (ViewBag.Alert == "Updated")
{
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Record has been successfully updated.</strong>
</div>
}
```

I was able to make the page reload when the grid was either adding a record, updating a record, or deleting a record by detecting the operation with the following javascript....

```
<script>
function onRequestEnd(e)
{
    var operationType = e.type;

    if(operationType == "destroy" || operationType == "create" || operationType == "update")
    {
        location.reload();
    }
}
</script>
```